# Custom message after plugin installation

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, installation

After an installation process, the translated manifest description from the sys.ini-file is shown in the Extension Manager. Unfortunately this text is also shown while editing the (published) plugin parameters.

**/plugins/system/my_plugin/manifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension type="plugin" version="3.8" group="system" method="upgrade">
<name>PLG_NAME</name>
<description>PLG_DESCRIPTION</description>
```

**/plugins/system/my_plugin/language/en-GB/en-GB.plg_system_my_plugin.sys.ini**

```
PLG_DESCRIPTION="This text is shown after installation AND as description of enabled plugins"
```

Is it possible to shown a custom message after installation/update in the Extension Manager? 
And only at this point.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely possible. You have to create/use an install `script.php` file in your installable plugin folder which will include tasks on different points of installation, uninstallation, update, preflight or postflight tasks:

For a module, a script class would look like this:

```
class mod_helloWorldInstallerScript
{

    public function __construct(JAdapterInstance $adapter) 
    {
        // construct here... it could be left empty
    }

    /*
    install, update, preflight... functions here
    */

    /**
    * Called on installation        
    */
    public function install(JAdapterInstance $adapter)
    {
        echo 'Your custom message on installation';
    }

    // In this function you can also display your custom message in
    // the Extension Manager after install ie.     
    function postflight($type, $parent) 
    {
        echo '<p>Anything here happens after the installation/update/uninstallation of the module</p>';
        echo JText::_('PLG_MY_CUSTOM_TEXT_AFTER_INSTALL');
    }

}
```

Same for plugins... except you call the class: `plg_mypluginInstallerScript`

You can study this subject more here: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file

or here at the bottom of this page:
https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files

Comment: Perfectly and incredible fast answered! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: The above two comments, while pleasant, are noise / unnecessary.  https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/12352